# Abiogenesis of solid-state organisms that reproduce through rock melting and magnetism

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, aliens, electromagnetism

When looking for alternatives to the classic carbon-based life I often found replies on why carbon is still the most likely element to base life on because it can create complex molecules, it can create bonds with lots of different elements, it's stable, with the most likely alternative being silicon, and the some other unlilkely alternatives like boron or sulphur, but then I wondered whether life forms based different processes altoghether would be possible. I tried to look for answers and found ideas on life based on fundamental forces other than electromagnetism like nuclear and gravity, but not what I'm looking for.

A solid-state organism that doesn't require liquid solvents like water and lots of different chemical processes to grow and reproduce but rather melts and rearranges materials through magnets, either permanents magnets in its body or electromagnets activated by electric currents.

Rather than gaining the necessary energy by 'eating' and processing other molecules these organisms would collect energy from lightnings or heat for example. I haven't thought about all the details yet but it would probably require some kind of biological circuit and some way to store the energy (maybe just in the most complex species).

My idea is that it could start as microscopic solid organisms that collect energy and create other similar organisms by melting the surrounding rocks to use as building blocks, then at some point evolve and start sticking to one another thanks to magnets, which would allow to create more complex life forms.

How would such an organism form naturally on a previously lifeless planet? How would it all start on a microscopic level? Would it even be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it even be possible?

I don't think it would be possible.

> A solid-state organism that doesn't require liquid solvents like water and lots of different chemical processes to grow and reproduce but rather melts and rearranges materials through magnets, either permanents magnets in its body or electromagnets activated by electric currents.

What you describe here is a top-down approach. We humans use a top-down approach, too, in making solid state devices, and we use nothing like molten materials and magnets: we use a series of complex processes, like thin film deposition, photolithography, ion implantation, plasma etching and so on, with which we manage to reach down to a few nanometers, well below biology scale.

Stay assured that if it was possible to make solid state devices with just molten materials and magnets, somebody in Korea, Taiwan or US would be making good money out of it.

That said...

> these organisms would collect energy from lightnings or heat for example.

Thermodynamic doesn't work that way: if you want to collect energy at low temperature and use it at higher temperature, you can't do it for free, that's why you need to plug your fridge to drink cold water while your soup cools down without any effort. And solid state doesn't want to melt itself, so I would stay away from lightnings.

Comment: Thanks, as for the last part maybe I wasn't clear enough on how they would melt materials near them. I thought about some kind of welding process using the eletricity gathered from lightnings (or generated in some way), not the cold organism transferring heat to the hot melting rock, although that would probably make the natural formation of such an organism even more of a stretch.